# Xubuntu persistence. Plop loading usb and no hard drive. -how to?

Tags: boot, usb, xubuntu, ipod

I have an old laptop that will not boot from usb, so I am using either a live cd or Plop linux to boot a live USB (I haven't decided which yet) of xubuntu 12.04.3-desktop-i386.

The laptop does not have a hard drive, so I am using a 60gb video ipod as an external hard drive.

I would like to save all changes to the os (programs added, settings changed, that sort of thing.) to a persistence file on the ipod, which would be read on boot.

How do?

Answer (score 0):

I would have thought it should be possible. The existing live CD/USB code supports persistence, it's just a question of creating a persistence file on the iPod and having the casper initrd scripts find it.

Once you've mounted the iPod, change directory to where it has appeared (usually /media/xxxx), and create a blank file with dd:

```
dd if=/dev/zero bs=$((1024*1024)) of=casper-rw count=<size in megs>
```

then format the file(!):

```
mke2fs casper-rw
```

After that, boot your live USB with the "persistent" command line option added, and it *should* work - you can check by running mount or losetup to see if the casper-rw file off the iPod has been mounted correctly.

If it doesn't work, it's worth downloading the source to the casper package, and examining the various start-up scripts to study the boot process. I've done things like this before and it's quite an interesting project :)